# Twilio voice recording survey

Tags: python, twilio

I am creating an app using the [twilio](https://www.twilio.com) API. My goal is to record a series of answers by call recipient but I am facing an issue that with asking next question and stopping the recording, to stop the call with a key press I have provided `finish_on_key` instead of finishing the call, it is repeating the code and the question. I am not sure where i am going wrong with this. My code is not executing after `response.record(finish_on_key='*')`.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a "URL" value for the "action" attribute of the "record" tag and you end up in a loop, just like described in the docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-action)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This seems hard to answer to me without the code. Can you post your code? Or even better a minimal, complete, verifiable code example? For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And take the tour!